# Is context.Subject.Identity supposed to be empty when calling UserInfo endpoint manually from client?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have a working IdentityServer implementation with custom ProfileService for custom claims. One thing I couldn't figure out if intended behavior or bug or my mistake is that when I call UserInfo endpoint manually from the client after authorization the `context.Subject.Identity` is empty. It's not empty and has correct user information during login/authorization process which I determine who the user is. Is this normal or is something wrong on my end or am I missing a point? Am I supposed to use `sub` value from claims instead of `context.Subject.Identity` in UserProfile endpoint?

Using IdentityServer4 1.2.1

Comment: What method of authentication are you using? Particularly, if you're authenticating via something like client auth, then you won't have access to the user.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: Hybrid flow